# Create a RAG system based on dates, upcoming and expired within Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, formatting, google-sheets-cell-format

[image]

I want to create a RAG system in google sheets based on dates in a cell. Column A will show a date when someone is trained on a topic and column B shows the due refresher date (3 years later). I want to set up a RAG system so that column B will show green if the dates are within 2 years from the training date, amber when there is one year left before the refresher is due and red when the refresher period has passed.

Comment: This doesn't look like a practical, detailed question about using Google Sheets. I'm not adding more detail as it will likely be closed and eventually deleted after the moderation strike.

Answer (score 0):

Try these conditional formatting custom formula rules for the range `B2:B`:

green: `=today() <= B2 - 2 * 365`

yellow: `=today() <= B2 - 365`

orange: `=today() <= B2`

red: `=len(B2) * (today() >= B2)`

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.